# List of countries moved to developed economies in the last 50 years

Tags: macroeconomics, national-accounts, information

I read in Bloomberg that five countries moved to advanced economies  in the last 50 years from developing economies and one of them was Singapore. Wondering what are the other four countries?

The link to the article is as follows.
https://bloom.bg/31s13gm

Comment: Did you see this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developed_country#Comparative_Table_(2019)?

Comment: Thanks for the link.